# Elasticsearch one record for one matching query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one elasticsearch index in which I have so many records. There is a field username, I want to get latest 1 post of each username by passing comma separated values, example ::

> john,shahid,mike,jolie

and I want latest 1 post of each usernames. How can I do this? I can do it by passing one username at a time but it will hit so many http requests. I want to do it in one request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a filtered `terms` aggregation coupled with a `top_hits` one in order to achieve what you need:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "username": [ "john", "shahid", "mike", "jolie" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "usernames": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "username": [ "john", "shahid", "mike", "jolie" ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_username": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "username"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top1": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1,
                "sort" : {"created_date" : "desc"}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This query is almost close to my requirement, but this is giving oldest record of each usernames. I need latest record. How to sort in desc order of created_date?

Comment: Everything is working fine for me now. I only changed bool": { "filter": {  to  bool": "must": [{ "query_string":  {  in your code  because it was giving error.

Answer (score 0):

This query can give you all the posts of these 4 ids sorted by post_date in descending order. You can process on that data to get the result.

```
  {
       "sort" : [
        { "post_date" : {"order" : "desc"}}
       ],
      "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
          "filter" : {
            "terms" : {
              "username" : ["john","shahid","mike","jolie]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This query is giving 20 records for "mike" but no records for other users, I need only 4 records as 4 usernames are there, 1 record for each user.